# how to check duplicate value in form before insert into database

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter-3

> I would like to check duplicate data when i insert duplicate in textbox it will display duplicate and I tried to insert not duplicate it display "Trying to get property of non-object"
>
> Controller

```
public function gamecheck(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); // load from validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gamename', 'Checkgamename', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    if($this->input->post()) {
        $this->load->model('game_m');
        $gamepost = $this->input->post('gamename');
        $getgame = $this->game_m->get_game($gamepost);

           if($getgame->gamename!==''){
            echo "duplicate";
           }else{
            echo "not duplicate";
           }
         }
      }
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('menu');
    $this->load->view('game/gamecheck');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

> Model

```
class Game_m extends CI_model{
public function get_game($gamepost) {
     $this->db->from('game');
     $this->db->where('gamename',$gamepost);
     return $this->db->get()->row();
    }
}
```

Comment: what are there in $getgame, can you please give response here ?

Comment: $getgame  fetch data from model Game_m.  in function get_game i select data from database table game in order to check value from post and data in database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for unique value you can use `is_unique[]` in `codeigniter` like below

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fieldname', 'Msg you want to show', 'required|is_unique[table.coloum]');
```

Answer (score -1):

for unique value i am using is_unique[] in codeigniter.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('gamename', 'Field is required', 'required|is_unique[game.gamename]');
```